# Trying to access a dictionary inside of a nested dictionary with a specific value

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary and I only want to access the return the data from the area with specific champion id. I only want to return the part with `championId` of 25.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
def champion_data(id):
    json = requests.get("https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/champion-mastery/v4/champion-masteries/by-summoner/"
                        + id + "?api_key=" + API_KEY).json()
    sleep(1.5)
    print(json[championid25])
```

and get back:

```
{'championId': 25,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 24672,
  'lastPlayTime': 1537120963000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 3072,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'}
```

data:

```
[{'championId': 63,
  'championLevel': 7,
  'championPoints': 212460,25
  'lastPlayTime': 1637560809000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 190860,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 3,
  'championLevel': 7,
  'championPoints': 191701,
  'lastPlayTime': 1636793279000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 170101,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 145,
  'championLevel': 7,
  'championPoints': 106932,
  'lastPlayTime': 1637128469000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 85332,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 11,
  'championLevel': 6,
  'championPoints': 71497,
  'lastPlayTime': 1635106390000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 49897,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 3,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 53,
  'championLevel': 7,
  'championPoints': 70960,
  'lastPlayTime': 1637328825000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 49360,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 157,
  'championLevel': 6,
  'championPoints': 65018,
  'lastPlayTime': 1636862668000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 43418,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 3,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 202,
  'championLevel': 6,
  'championPoints': 54801,
  'lastPlayTime': 1630352794000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 33201,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 2,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 555,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 50975,
  'lastPlayTime': 1632603842000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 29375,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 2,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 81,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 50172,
  'lastPlayTime': 1636424397000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 28572,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 55,
  'championLevel': 6,
  'championPoints': 48962,
  'lastPlayTime': 1636795492000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 27362,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 1,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 517,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 41944,
  'lastPlayTime': 1634543048000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 20344,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 1,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 497,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 41850,
  'lastPlayTime': 1637203723000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 20250,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 2,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 412,
  'championLevel': 6,
  'championPoints': 41553,
  'lastPlayTime': 1637324149000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 19953,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 2,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 102,
  'championLevel': 6,
  'championPoints': 37943,
  'lastPlayTime': 1624406521000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 16343,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 1,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 21,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 37578,
  'lastPlayTime': 1614146233000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 15978,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 84,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 36785,
  'lastPlayTime': 1617760871000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 15185,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 126,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 33577,
  'lastPlayTime': 1636421589000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 11977,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 103,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 33168,
  'lastPlayTime': 1636782617000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 11568,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 777,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 33016,
  'lastPlayTime': 1637548813000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 11416,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 2,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 19,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 33005,
  'lastPlayTime': 1637383815000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 11405,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 2,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 131,
  'championLevel': 6,
  'championPoints': 30754,
  'lastPlayTime': 1637379229000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 9154,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 5,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 25998,
  'lastPlayTime': 1625947585000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 4398,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': True,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'},
 {'championId': 25,
  'championLevel': 5,
  'championPoints': 24672,
  'lastPlayTime': 1537120963000,
  'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 3072,
  'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0,
  'chestGranted': False,
  'tokensEarned': 0,
  'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'}
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use generator comprehension:

```py
output = next(d for d in data if d['championId'] == 25)
print(output)
# {'championId': 25, 'championLevel': 5, 'championPoints': 24672, 'lastPlayTime': 1537120963000, 'championPointsSinceLastLevel': 3072, 'championPointsUntilNextLevel': 0, 'chestGranted': False, 'tokensEarned': 0, 'summonerId': 'e4W_5wmX4nTbJ81NGZRsYLp-Y76aIK5E9fuMjJ8LrQHH2N8'}
```

This assumes that there *exists* a dict satisfying the condition.

If you do not want to assume it, you can instead try:

```py
output = data_filtered[0] if (data_filtered := [d for d in data if d['championId'] == 25]) else {}
```

This returns an empty dictionary if no such dict is found.